# Onmouseover change CSS class from other element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an JS, but since I'm not an expert on that, maybe someone could help me. I was searching for that in Google and in Stack Overflow, but didn't find what I need. I just found `onmouseover` that change the class in element itself. But I want something different:

I want to make a `onmouseover` on `a` tag to change the class `closed` to `open` in other element. Example:

`<a href="#" onmouseover="<active event>">Link</a>`

`<ul class="dropdown closed"><li>Item</li></ul>`

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you include jQuery:

Add id for your elements:

```
<a href="#" id="a1">Link</a>
<ul class="dropdown closed" id="ul1"><li>Item</li></ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#a1").mouseover(function(){
  $("#ul1").addClass("open").removeClass("closed")
})
```

Comment: Thanks. It's exactly what I needed, but didn't work like I thought... I was trying to make dropdown menu from Foundation 4 work with mouseover ("Os Desbravadores" menu: http://bit.ly/11eY85I)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<a href="#" onmouseover="changeClass">Link</a>`

And JS:

```
function changeClass() {
    document.getElementById("other-element").className = "open";
}
```

More advanced JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eRdHJ/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" onmouseover=$("ul.dropdown").addClass("open").removeClass("closed")>Link</a>

<ul class="dropdown closed"><li>Item</li></ul>
```

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eRdHJ/2/

Answer (score 1):

This will access the first `<ul>` on the page. To narrow it down you need to do a `getElementById` first to get the elements based on tag name from that point. It will then only select the children from that tag with that certain ID-name;

```
<script>
    function changeUl() {
        // Get the first found UL, anywhere in the body
        document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].className = 'otherName';
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onmouseover="changeUl();">Link</a>
```

***With ID***

```
<script>
    function changeUl() {
        var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
        wrapper.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].className = 'otherName';
    }
</script>

<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="#" onmouseover="changeUl();">Link</a>
</div>
```

You might want to check if there are any found tho. `[0]` might trigger an undefined/error if there are no `<ul>` found.